rig joint outside of skeleton
I have rigged the body and added the single bones that float in an area of the object. But when I weight and transfer the file as all options, Collada, fbx, gltf, I find the single floating bones are missing. They have about 15% weight on them. Vertex shares 5 bones as a whole to =100%. What am I missing?

Hello, please share your file.

It sounds like your separate bone exists as an separate Armature.
If so, before exporting you should merge all armatures into the single one.
You can do it in two steps:
1) [in Pose Mode] reset every armature to the rest pose:
Press A to select all bones, then Pose > Clear Transform > All
2) [in Object Mode] apply armatures' transforms:
Click-select floating bone > shift-select main armature > Ctrl+A > All Transforms> then Ctrl+J (to join armatures)

(!)
Sometimes applying transforms could mess with the animation, so double-check your animations before exporting.
Also I recommend you to back-up your .blend file before doing all these steps.

